# Definition of "distance"; necessary and sufficient conditions

Tags: geometry

I was watching a video about p-adic distances that showed some very counterintuitive results using that distance function. In it, the professor said that a distance function is any that satisfies the following conditions:

1. $d(a,b) \ge 0$
2. $d(a,b) = d(b,a)$
3. $d(a,c) \le d(a,b) + d(b,c)$  (triangle inequality)

To me, those seem like necessary conditions for a distance, but are they sufficient?

If we define $d(a,b) = 2$ then it satisfies all the conditions. But that seems ludicrous.

Comment: You also need $d(a,a)=0$ for a distance function. You can add this to your metric example and have a valid distance function i.e everything is 2 distant from everything else

Comment: The first condition is usually written something like, "$d(a,b) \geq 0$, with $d(a,b) = 0$ if and only if $a=b$." Alternatively, the $>$ and $=$ cases can be described in separate conditions.